# WP Customazation API doesn't save the default Value

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, theme-options

Heyo,

I have a problem with the Customazation API of my own Theme. I want to make a specific Text in my theme ediable.

My functions.php looks like so:

```
/** ++++++++++++  Editable Text   +++++++++++++ */
function myTheme_register( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_section('text_section', array(
    'title' => __('Edit Text', 'myTheme'),
    'priority' => 30,
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('text_setting', array(
    'default' => 'This is a sentence',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'text_control', array(
    'label' => __('Change Text', 'myTheme'),
    'section' => 'text_section',
    'settings' => 'text_setting',
)));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'myTheme_register');
```

And I included it in my header.php like so:

```
...
<p><?php echo get_theme_mod('text_setting'); ?></p>
...
```

Now if I save these files and view my site the HTML code looks like so:

```
...
<p></p>
...
```

But if I go into the customaizer of the Theme it looks like so:

```
...
<p>This is a sentence</p>
...
```

Now to my question: How can I make the default value of the setting to the default SAVED setting without going into the Customizer first?

I hope that question makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, its mainly for demo purposes within Customizer.
If you want a default to be output, in your output do this:

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'text_setting', __( 'Default value here', 'text-domain' ) );
```

Comment: That's right. You should build up an array of default values (e.g. in a global variable) that you can re-use in the `get_theme_mod()` calls as well as when defining the `default` parameter for an added customizer setting. I consider this current best practice.